# how can https://jwt.io/ decrypt jwt token without knowing the secretKey

Tags: jwt, token

this is a simple function to create `jwt token` based on `id`

```
 createAccessToken(id: string) {
 const token = sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });
 return token;
    }
```

now when I give the token to https://jwt.io/ without specifing the `secretkey` the website can still decrypt it

[image]

how can this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWTs are not *encrypted*, but basically just base64 *encoded*, cf. [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519).
As you can see on https://jwt.io/, you need to provide the secret key if you want to *verify the signature*.